# MAC OS X Pebble SDK 3.0 error building: Compilation error InverterLayer

Tags: python, ssl, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, pebble-js

A few months ago I was running pebble SDK 3.0 on my mac and it worked perfectly, I ran my apps with the basalt emulator.

Recently I cleaned(wiped) my mac because it was running slow. Today I was going to run my apps again but I obviously didn't have the Pebble SDK installed.

I installed it using the brew command that appears on the pebble developer website: http://developer.getpebble.com/sdk/download/

```
brew install pebble/pebble-sdk/pebble-sdk
```

I found the directory over here:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0
```

I tried to run pebble build but I remembered I needed to for and clone the pebbles repository.
I did that and then when I do pebble build it starts building fine but then, this happens:

```
[17/63] Start build for aplite: 
[25/63] app_resources.pbpack.manifest: build/resources/aplite/images/menu_icon.pbi build/resources/aplite/images/logo_splash.pbi build/resources/aplite/images/tile_splash.pbi build/resources/aplite/fonts/UbuntuMono-Regular.ttf.MONO_FONT_14.pfo ../Pebble/common/tools/pbpack_meta_data.py -> build/aplite/app_resources.pbpack.manifest
[28/63] c: src/simply/simply.c -> build/src/simply/simply.c.28.o
[31/63] c: src/simply/simply_msg.c -> build/src/simply/simply_msg.c.28.o
[35/63] c: src/simply/simply_splash.c -> build/src/simply/simply_splash.c.28.o
In file included from ../src/simply/simply.c:6:0:
../src/simply/simply_stage.h:102:3: error: unknown type name 'InverterLayer'
../src/simply/simply_splash.c: In function 'simply_splash_create':
../src/simply/simply_splash.c:45:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'window_set_fullscreen' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
In file included from ../src/simply/simply_msg.c:5:0:
../src/simply/simply_stage.h:102:3: error: unknown type name 'InverterLayer'

Waf: Leaving directory `/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0/pebblejs/build'
Build failed
 -> task in 'basalt/pebble-app.elf' failed (exit status 1): 
    {task 4378463632: c simply.c -> simply.c.28.o}
['arm-none-eabi-gcc', '-std=c99', '-mcpu=cortex-m3', '-mthumb', '-ffunction-sections', '-fdata-sections', '-g', '-Os', '-D_TIME_H_', '-Wall', '-Wextra', '-Werror', '-Wno-unused-parameter', '-Wno-error=unused-function', '-Wno-error=unused-variable', '-Wno-address', '-Wno-type-limits', '-Wno-missing-field-initializers', '-fPIE', '-I/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0/pebblejs/Pebble/basalt/include', '-I/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0/Pebble/basalt/include', '-I/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0/pebblejs/build', '-I/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0/pebblejs', '-I/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0/pebblejs/build/src', '-I/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0/pebblejs/src', '-I/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0/pebblejs/build/basalt', '-I/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0/pebblejs/basalt', '-DRELEASE', '-DPBL_PLATFORM_BASALT', '-DPBL_COLOR', '-DPBL_SDK_3', '-D__FILE_NAME__="simply.c"', '../src/simply/simply.c', '-c', '-o', 'src/simply/simply.c.28.o']
 -> task in 'basalt/pebble-app.elf' failed (exit status 1): 
    {task 4378501264: c simply_splash.c -> simply_splash.c.28.o}
['arm-none-eabi-gcc', '-std=c99', '-mcpu=cortex-m3', '-mthumb', '-ffunction-sections', '-fdata-sections', '-g', '-Os', '-D_TIME_H_', '-Wall', '-Wextra', '-Werror', '-Wno-unused-parameter', '-Wno-error=unused-function', '-Wno-error=unused-variable', '-Wno-address', '-Wno-type-limits', '-Wno-missing-field-initializers', '-fPIE', '-I/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0/pebblejs/Pebble/basalt/include', '-I/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0/Pebble/basalt/include', '-I/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0/pebblejs/build', '-I/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0/pebblejs', '-I/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0/pebblejs/build/src', '-I/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0/pebblejs/src', '-I/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0/pebblejs/build/basalt', '-I/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0/pebblejs/basalt', '-DRELEASE', '-DPBL_PLATFORM_BASALT', '-DPBL_COLOR', '-DPBL_SDK_3', '-D__FILE_NAME__="simply_splash.c"', '../src/simply/simply_splash.c', '-c', '-o', 'src/simply/simply_splash.c.28.o']
 -> task in 'basalt/pebble-app.elf' failed (exit status 1): 
    {task 4378464016: c simply_msg.c -> simply_msg.c.28.o}
['arm-none-eabi-gcc', '-std=c99', '-mcpu=cortex-m3', '-mthumb', '-ffunction-sections', '-fdata-sections', '-g', '-Os', '-D_TIME_H_', '-Wall', '-Wextra', '-Werror', '-Wno-unused-parameter', '-Wno-error=unused-function', '-Wno-error=unused-variable', '-Wno-address', '-Wno-type-limits', '-Wno-missing-field-initializers', '-fPIE', '-I/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0/pebblejs/Pebble/basalt/include', '-I/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0/Pebble/basalt/include', '-I/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0/pebblejs/build', '-I/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0/pebblejs', '-I/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0/pebblejs/build/src', '-I/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0/pebblejs/src', '-I/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0/pebblejs/build/basalt', '-I/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0/pebblejs/basalt', '-DRELEASE', '-DPBL_PLATFORM_BASALT', '-DPBL_COLOR', '-DPBL_SDK_3', '-D__FILE_NAME__="simply_msg.c"', '../src/simply/simply_msg.c', '-c', '-o', 'src/simply/simply_msg.c.28.o']

[ERROR   ] A compilation error occurred
```

I am not sure what to do.
Thanks!

Kevin

Comment: *For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning* Have you checked that out yet?

Comment: I fixed the insecure platform warning by running this command on the terminal then closing it and opening a new window: sudo pip install requests[security] But I keep getting error on the building as if the sdk did not recognize some files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: Solved it!

PROBLEM:
I read more about the new sdks that pebble has been updating and it seems that the new one deprecated the inverterLayer and some other functions that is why it wasn't compiling.

FIX:
What I did is I went on to the examples page on the developer.pebble website and browse one of them on github, cloned that one which eliminated the problems I had, and then I copied my code and ran it.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. I would recommend a look at our migration guide too: http://developer.getpebble.com/sdk/migration-guide/